# Convert text (days, minutes, seconds) into days

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

1. `18hr 28m 49s`
2. `18 days 19hr 12m 30s`

I have an Excel  sheet with text values (like the examples above).

Is there a way I can convert them into days such that:

- If I have 18hrs, it rounds off to the nearest day and becomes 1 Day.
- If it is 18 Days and 19hrs, it becomes 19days

Note that those values are in text format. Not Date. Not time.

Comment: Just to verify, you show hours, minutes, and seconds labels as immediately adjacent to the value.  The days label is separated by a space.  Is this pattern literally correct and consistent?  Does the cell contain the quote marks around the string?

Comment: There are no quotes around the string. Its just plain text separated by spaces

Comment: And the first question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula

`=IF(MID(A1,FIND("hr",A1,1)-2,2)>12,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("day",A1,1)),VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("day",A1,1)-1))+1&"days",1&"day"))`

I used 12hr as limit to increment 1 day you can change it like you want
Whatever the text is, it will find "hr" and "day" and calculate according to it.
Also write hr and day (in the formula) the same way as it is in your text in order to let the formula find it.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many Thanks Yass

Answer (score 1):

It seems overkill, but you can use a User Defined Function, this is the code:

```
Public Function toDays(datestring As String)
    Dim datearray() As String
    datearray = Split(datestring, " ")
    totaldays = 0
    totalhours = 0
    totalmin = 0
    totalsecs = 0
    For i = LBound(datearray) To UBound(datearray)
        newdata = datearray(i)
        If IsNumeric(newdata) = True Then
            totaldays = totaldays + newdata
            i = i + 1
        Else
            For j = 1 To Len(newdata)
                m = Mid(newdata, j, 1)
                If IsNumeric(m) = False Then
                    separation = j
                    j = Len(newdata)
                End If
            Next j
            numvalue = Mid(newdata, 1, separation - 1)
            measurevalue = LCase(Mid(newdata, separation))
            Select Case measurevalue
                Case Is = "hr"
                    totalhours = totalhours + numvalue
                Case Is = "m"
                    totalmin = totalmin + numvalue
                Case Is = "s"
                    totalsecs = totalsecs + numvalue
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
    finalresult = Round(totaldays + (totalhours / 24) + (totalmin / 1440) + (totalsecs / 86400))
    toDays = finalresult  & " days"
End Function
```

Open Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> right click on `This Workbook` and insert a new module. Paste the code on the right side of the screen.

Now if your data is in cell `A1` then in cell `A2` you should put `=toDays(A1)`.

Comment: Let me also try this out to see what it does. Thank you JCBERMU